# Margin: 0 auto not working IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a site - http://81.201.129.45/~nichol/ which is working fine in firefox and safari but in IE the margin: 0 auto set on the containers isn't working and the site is just display as left aligned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dear see my answer and remove the script and place it in <head> tag.

Comment: Please don't deface your question, just select the answer that helped you the most.  Or add a new one that details what you did to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not including a DOCTYPE in your page, include that and it works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

EDIT: Your DOCTYPE is in place, now that i look at the source, but you're including a large chunk of javascript that is supposed to be placed inside of your `head` tag, the DOCTYPE needs to be absolutely at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Your document seems to be on Quirks mode. Try specifying explicitly the document type at the top

Answer (score 0):

Wow you actually have `<script>` element before `<html>`... Move that to before `</head>` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the JavaScript code before the doctype?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below script from top of the page and put it in head tag. You site is in quirks mode.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_required(field,alerttxt)
{
with (field)
  {
  if (value==null||value=="")
    {
    alert(alerttxt);return false;
    }
  else
    {
    return true;
    }
  }
}
function validate_email(field,alerttxt)
{
with (field)
  {
  apos=value.indexOf("@");
  dotpos=value.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (apos<1||dotpos-apos<2)
    {alert(alerttxt);return false;}
  else {return true;}
  }
}
function validate_number(field,alerttxt)
{
with (field)
  {
  if (value != '11')
    {
    alert(alerttxt);return false;}
  else {return true;}
  }
}
function validate_form(thisform)
{
with (thisform)
  {
  if (validate_required(request_name,"Name must be filled out!")==false)
  {request_name.focus();return false;}
  if (validate_required(request_email,"Email address must be entered!")==false)
  {request_email.focus();return false;}
  if (validate_email(request_email,"Not a valid e-mail address!")==false)
    {request_email.focus();return false;}


  if (validate_number(request_number,"Not the correct answer for 7 + 4")==false)
    {request_number.focus();return false;}

  }
}
</script>
```